# Simpler alternative to AngelScript

Tags: c++, scripting

I want to give players the ability to create and share bullet patterns for a shoot'em up.

The pattern scripts should have all the common programming stuff like loops, if/else, variables, and so on.

But in the end, I just want them to call a "spawn bullet at X, Y with Z angle and A speed" in the C++ game.

To spawn a circle of bullets, the user should only have to write a script with a for loop that goes from 0 to 360 and calls the spawn bullet function on every iteration.

I tried integrating AngelScript, but I am getting nowhere - it looks way to complex for a simple task like this one.

Is there an easy to integrate library that can solve my problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embedding scripting is never easy.

[Squirrel](http://www.squirrel-lang.org/) or [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) might be simpler as long you don't plan to use classes. For example you probably won't need a class for the bullets, a function SpawnBullet(x, y, angle, speed) would probably be enough. (If you need classes AngelScript takes quite a bit of work from your shoulders because it was designed to interact with C++ classes in the first case.)

Comment: In the end, I decided to go with Lua, using LuaWrapper to make the syntax prettier.

https://code.google.com/p/luawrapper/